# Using Paypal Express Checkout in appcelerator titanium

Tags: php, paypal, titanium-mobile, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

I am developing a mobile commerce application in Appcelerator Titanium and using Paypal as my payment gateway. I am using the Paypal's Express Checkout mechanism and doing all the Paypal interaction stuff in php scripts and calling those scripts through xhr object. My php scripts are working perfectly in the browser and payment is done displaying the thank you message, BUT when I try to call the php scripts from the app it redirects to paypal sandbox page displaying the message "Please login to use sandbox features" and nothing else.I am stuck here and can't do any advancement. It is to be noted that I am already logged in to sandbox through my sandbox account? I've spent so much time on searching this problem but couldn't get it working. Please help me what I am doing wrong here? I really need your help. Any help in this regard will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the PayPal module on the Appcelerator Marketplace? It's much easier to integrate and it's free:
https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/780?693288467

Comment: HI, Thanks for reply. I've downloaded it but don't know how to integrate it with titanium. Also I heard from different forums that this modules require some subscription or registration etc...

Comment: This module you subscribe to yes, but it is free and will remain so.  
  
To integrate with titanium you need to do three things:
1. Add the module into the correct folder structure - 
Macintosh HD > Library > Application Support > Titanium > modules > PLATFORM > ti.paypal > VERSION  
2.Add the module to your tiapp.xml file.  
<modules>
<module platform='PLATFORM' version='VERSIONNUMBER'>ti.paypal<module> 
</modules>  
3. Require the module in which you can see an example of by copying the example app.js that comes with the module into your project